# A divergent sequence whose average sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Can we find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$, but
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a<\infty?$$
Does the sequence $\{\ln(\ln(n))\}$ satisfy this condition? If yes, how can we show that? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to find such a sequence. I'll do it for functions, this will give an alternative way.

Assume a locally integrable function $f$ on $[0,+\infty)$ tends to $+\infty$ at $+\infty$. We will show that the antiderivative $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ satisfies
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{F(x)}{x}=+\infty.
$$

Fix $C>0$. Then there is $x_0>0$ such that $f(x)\geq 2C$ for all $x\geq x_0$. Thus
$$
F(x)=\int_0^{x_0}f+\int_{x_0}^xf\geq 2C(x-x_0)+\int_0^{x_0}f=2Cx+D
$$
hence
$$
\frac{F(x)}{x}\geq 2C+\frac{D}{x}\qquad\forall x\geq x_0.
$$
Now there is $x_1>x_0$ such that $D/x\geq -C$ for all $x\geq x_1$. Therefore
$$
\frac{F(x)}{x}\geq 2C+\frac{D}{x}\geq 2C-C=C\qquad\forall x\geq x_1.
$$
So we have show that $F(x)/x$ tends to $+\infty$ as claimed.

Now apply this to series which fulfill your assumptions. One way to do that is to construct a piecewise constant function $f$ which takes the value $a_n$ on $[n,n+1)$. Then $f(x)$ behaves like $a_n$, and $F(x)$ like the partial sums.

Answer (score 7):

Sequence $(\ln \ln n)$ does not satisfy your condition. No sequence can satisfy your condition if $\lim a_n = +\infty$.

Suppose the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies your condition and converges to *positive* infinity. Let $b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. We shall prove that $(b_n)$ is unbounded.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary positive number. There is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n \geq n_0$ we have $a_n > A$. Then, for any $n \geq n_0$,
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_0}a_i + \sum_{i=n_0+1}^n a_i\right) \geq
\frac{A(n-n_0)+const}{n}
$$
As $n $ goes to $\infty$, the RHS converges to $A$, which means that for a sufficiently large $n$ we have $b_n > A - 1$. Since $A$ is arbitrary, sequence $(b_n)$ is unbounded and doesn't have a finite limit.

Still, if $a_n \to \infty$ means *unsigned* infinity, then one can build such an example. For instance:
$$
a_n = (-1)^n \ln \left[\frac{n+1}{2}\right].
$$

Answer (score 3):

In fact, we have the following Abelian theorem:

**Theorem.** If $a_n \to \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in [-\infty. \infty]$, then its average also tends to the limit $\alpha$. That is,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \alpha\in [-\infty. \infty] \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k = \alpha. $$

The proof for the case $\alpha = \pm\infty$ does not differ so much from that for the finite case.

Comment: @julien, Abelian theorems refer to the family of theorems concerning the problem of proving that weaker summation methods imply generalized summation methods. This example deals with the case where ordinary summation method implies Cesaro summation method. The set of theorems concerning the converse direction is called Tauberian theorems. and yes, you may regard as a apecial case of the Cesaro-Stolz theorem, which is a discrete analogue of the L'hospital's rule.

Comment: Ah, Cesaro-Stolz is the name, then. Where I studied, it was simply called Cesaro... Thanks for the response.