# Prove that the sequence $(\bar{a})_{n}$ is divergent if $|a_{n}| \geq n$ for infinitly many n.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence. Define $\bar{a} = (a_{1} + ... + a_{n})/n$.

Prove that the sequence $(\bar{a})_{n}$ is divergent if $|a_{n}| \geq n$ for infinitly many n.

My thoughts: It is evident that $(a_{n})$ is divergent since unbounded. But this doesnt say anything about $(\bar{a}_{n})$...

Then I found [A divergent sequence whose average sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324338/a-divergent-sequence-whose-average-sequence-converges) and at first thought that the post by Dan Shved is very useful.

But now I am very confused since my problem is slightly different: Obviously in my problem there is no assumption that $(a_{n}) \to \infty$ but only that $\infty$ or $-\infty$ are accumulation points...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a_{n_{k}}\geq n_{k}$ for $k=1,2,...$ and that $\overline{a}_{n}\rightarrow L$ for some $L\in{\bf{R}}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n_{k}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k}}a_{i}=\frac{a_{n_{k}}}{n_{k}}+\frac{n_{k}-1}{n_{k}}\frac{1}{n_{k}-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k}-1}a_{i}\geq 1+\frac{n_{k}-1}{n_{k}}\frac{1}{n_{k}-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k}-1}a_{i},
\end{align*}
taking $k\rightarrow\infty$, then $L\geq 1+L$, a contradiction.